# The difference between pandas Timedelta and timedelta64[ns]?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I want to use the function total_seconds.

I obtain the difference between two dates by subtracting the beginning from the end.

```
df["diff"] = (df["End"] - df["Start"])
```

which yields:

```
0      0 days 00:12:08
1      0 days 00:18:56
2      0 days 00:17:17
3      0 days 00:48:46
4      0 days 00:21:02
             ...      
7015   0 days 00:14:32
7016   0 days 00:08:33
7017   0 days 00:19:38
7018   0 days 00:18:41
7019   0 days 00:37:35
Name: diff, Length: 7020, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

There is a function [total seconds](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.total_seconds.html). But it doesn't work the `df["diff"]` that I created. Is `timedelta64[ns]` something different?

The function `total_seconds()` works if I call `pd.Timedelta()` on an individual element of the `df["diff"]` and than call `total_seconds()`.

I would like some clarification on dtype here and how to use the total_seconds function on the whole series.

Comment: `timedelta64[ns]` data type is used to implement the pandas Timedelta class. To access its methods in a pd.Series, use the dt accessor, e.g. `.dt.total_seconds()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Timedelta.total_seconds` method to access the total seconds of a single instance of `Timedelta` like:

```
>>> df['diff'].iloc[0].total_seconds()
728.0
```

But if you want to access the total seconds of a list (a `Series`) of `Timedelta` instances, you have to use the accessor `dt` because the list is a `TimedeltaIndex` (a collection of `Timedelta` instances):

```
>>> df['diff'].dt.total_seconds()
0        728.0
1       1136.0
2       1037.0
3       2926.0
4       1262.0
7015     872.0
7016     513.0
7017    1178.0
7018    1121.0
7019    2255.0
Name: diff, dtype: float64
```

Suppose your example:

```
data = {'diff': ['0 days 00:12:08', '0 days 00:18:56', '0 days 00:17:17']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You can convert each value:

```
>>> df['diff'].apply(pd.Timedelta)
0   0 days 00:12:08
1   0 days 00:18:56
2   0 days 00:17:17
Name: diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

# OR

>>> [pd.Timedelta(x) for x in df['diff']]
[Timedelta('0 days 00:12:08'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:18:56'),
 Timedelta('0 days 00:17:17')]
```

Or you can convert the whole list:

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(df['diff'])
0   0 days 00:12:08
1   0 days 00:18:56
2   0 days 00:17:17
Name: diff, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

# OR

>>> pd.TimedeltaIndex(df['diff'])
TimedeltaIndex(['0 days 00:12:08', '0 days 00:18:56', '0 days 00:17:17'],
               dtype='timedelta64[ns]', name='diff', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about the dt accessor, I guess I just forgot, because you don't need if you are using datetime as the index.

Answer (score 1):

You are not far off. See code below:

```
df["diff"] = (df["End"] - df["Start"]).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

In action

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'begin' : ['08:00', '10:00', '14:00'], 
                   'end'   : ['14:00', '17:00', '22:00']})
```

Solution; Seconds

```
df['diff_hours']=(pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format="%H:%M")-pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], format="%H:%M")).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Solution minutes

```
df['diff_hours']=(pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format="%H:%M")-pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], format="%H:%M")).astype('timedelta64[s]')/60
```

or

```
df['diff_hours']=(pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format="%H:%M")-pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], format="%H:%M")).astype('timedelta64[m]')
```

Pandas has clearly documented the [Timedelta limitations](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html). This is how I understand it;

DataFrame/Series operations of substraction of a datetime return  construct timedelta[ns] series as the native timedelta resolution. You can therefore not apply `.astype('timedelta64[ns]')` in the conversion to datetime frequencies. It returns itself. This explains why you end up with `0 days 00:12:08` if you try to `.astype('timedelta64[ns]')`

To convert to other frequencies, you have to divide by a numeric timedelta or astype to a specific timedelta which of course cannot be `timedelta64[ns]` itself.

You realize, `df['diff_hours']=(pd.to_datetime(df['end'], format="%H:%M")-pd.to_datetime(df['begin'], format="%H:%M")).dt.total_seconds()` works. because as explained in [python documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html), behind the hood it is astyping  to a specific `[timedelta type][2]` (see image below for timedelta types) in this case total number of seconds in the timedelta Series.

[image: The timedelta types available are listed]

You realize only `.astype('timedelta64[ns]')` leave the outcome of any datetime substration in the format  `0 days 00:12:08`. Even picosecond (`.astype('timedelta64[ps]')`) which is much less that nanosecond gets converted

Comment: See my explanation happy to clarify if needed